# Water damaged YN568EXii. Need help with parts

Tags: yongnuo

I recently washed one of my YN568EXii in sea water. It made a pop sound, gave some smoke and so I removed batteries.

I opened it up after I reached home and i see that there's one capacitor blown up. There's no other visible damage. I cleaned the insides.

Thing still boots up but that cap doesn't like it and pops.

Can anyone tell me what capacitor was in this spot?
Or is there a schematic available?
Or is this pcb spare available?[image]

Comment: I'm no electrician but I'll be honest that board looks highly corroded, considering what a capacitor does I'd strongly urge you to reconsider doing this work.

Comment: Just FYI, removing the batteries and leaving a speedlight alone for 24 hours [can still result in a capacitor holding a >200V charge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mgpbD0IFvw). I.e., just removing the batteries didn't actually render your flash's capacitor safe to work on.

Comment: Technically, the salt water seems to have discharged it. Sea water is *roughly* the worst fluid to get into electronics I suspect... I'm half certain the SMD under the top left screw hole has some burn marks next to it too.

Comment: Well, the board itself is not corroded, there were deposits that were cleaned. All open metal was tinned so fortunately only rust was on screw heads. There was ~15 days between dipping in water for 2 seconds and opening up. Also, this is not the cap that goes 200V, I believe that one is on the other side of this board (dont know how high this one goes though). After cleaning deposits, board looks feasible, so i could give it a try if I know which part is that. Or I could replace the whole board if I can find it somewhere.